# Why javascript code is not being loaded inside coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a coldfusion file(.cfm) which calls another .cfm file where script tag is defined having alert function. When i run this file, it doesn't load javascript code. What is potential issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be an issue with the way your paths are structured? Is it even pointed at the right page in the right folder?

Comment: Do you maybe need `cfoutput`-tags around the `script` tag? Why nest `script` tag in a `table` tag?

Comment: Open your developer tools' console and look for any errors. Also, do a `view-source` on the rendered page to see if that code even rendered to the browser.

Comment: One potential issue is that the NumofChildren variable has a value of 0.

Comment: Perhaps you have a CFSETTING being executed that has CFOutputOnly set to true?  If so then the previously mentioned comment about adding cfoutput tags should fix things for you.  This is assuming that the CFIF statement is evaluating to true so that the files get included and that no errors within your browsers dev console.

Answer (score 0):

Test with `<cfinclude template="/Features/lic/Features/Convictions/ActionPages/dsp_lic_sub_convictions.cfm">`